Lower bound for the number of groups of order $p^2q^2r^2$
Let $f(n)$ the number of groups of order $n$ up to isomorphism and $p$, $q$ and $r$ distinct primes being $p<q<r$
I am currently working on this conjecture:
$$f(pqr)^2\leq f(p^2q^2r^2)$$
I know that:
$$f(p^2qr)\leq f(p^2q^2r^2)$$
$$f(pq^2r)\leq f(p^2q^2r^2)$$
$$f(pqr^2)\leq f(p^2q^2r^2)$$
$$2.f(p^2q^2)\leq f(p^2q^2r^2)$$
$$2.f(p^2r^2)\leq f(p^2q^2r^2)$$
$$2.f(q^2r^2)\leq f(p^2q^2r^2)$$
$f(pqr)$ has 6 possible results:
$$f(pqr)=1$$
$$f(pqr)=2$$
$$f(pqr)=3$$
$$f(pqr)=4$$
$$f(pqr)=p+2$$
$$f(pqr)=p+4$$
When the number of groups of $pqr$ is less than 4, the conjecture is valid. However, this is not being helpful in proving the main conjecture. Even with these statements, I can't find lower bounds stronger than 8 for $f(p^2q^2r^2)$
How can I find a better lower bound for $f(p^2q^2r^2)$?
